# Como hacer para que el evento se ejecute varias veces?

Tags: javascript, html, css, eventos, onclick

Ya he intentado con for pero aun asi no funciona

```
 

        Hola Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, obcaecati, ndis consequuntur dolores cupiditate nulla ducimus dolorem similique quasi ipsam asperiores officia. Odit voluptate fugit, ducimus explicabo vel mollitia est?
        
        
    
    
        const para = document.querySelector("p")
        const boton = document.querySelector("#boton-1");
        const botonOne = document.querySelector("#boton-2");
        for (let i = 0; i
```

Comment: Hola Antonio y bienvenido a stackoverflow por favor incluye un ejemplo ejecutable, el codigo que incluyes no esta debidamente formateado y tiene errores claros de sintaxis

Comment: muchas gracias soy nuevo en stackoverflow como puedo hacer eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es, pues, que cuando pulsas el botón, te imprima por consola x numero de veces el texto `lorem imsum`.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    getElements();
})

function getElements(){
    var p   =   document.querySelector("p").innerHTML;
    var btn =   document.querySelector('button');
    btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        sayWord(p);
    })
}

function sayWord(p){
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
        console.log(p);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/003.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hola Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, obcaecati, ndis consequuntur dolores cupiditate nulla ducimus dolorem similique quasi ipsam asperiores officia. Odit voluptate fugit, ducimus explicabo vel mollitia est?
</p>

<button>PULSAME</button>
</body>
</html>
```

El bucle for que tu tienes está incompleto, por tanto, no haría nada.

La sintaxis del for es sencilla:

```
for(var i = 0;) /*Esto inicializa el bucle asignándole la variable i al valor 0.
Puede ser cualquier valor, y puedes darle el valor de la variable dentro o fuera del bucle, otro ejemplo con i fuera del bucle:

var i;
for(i = 0;)

/*Una vez hecho eso, tienes que fijar la salida del bucle:*/

for(var i = 0; i < 5) /*hacemos que la variable i valga 0.
Y cuando i sea menor que 5 se ejecute, cuando i sea igual a 5, ya no se ejecutará.
También puedes hacer i > 5; i <= 5; i >= 5...Todo son operandos.*/

//finalizamos la sintaxis del bucle con la itereación (añadir +1)
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){/*...Aqui el codigo a ejecutar, en este caso
El console.log(p)...*/}
```

También puedes definir tu mismo, mediante el prompt, cuándo quieres que se cierre el bucle:

```
function sayWord(p){
    var n = prompt('Inserta un valor de cierre del bucle');
        while(!n || isNaN(n)){
            var n = prompt('inserta un valor de cierre del bucle');
        }

    for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
        console.log(p);
    }
}
```

Cambiando la función sayWord(p). Si la analizas detenidamente, verás que el bucle for tiene como cierre a i < n. Siendo n la variable metida por el prompt. Si quieres verificar que n sea si o si un número, tienes que meterlo dentro de un bucle while con el comando isNaN(n), esto comprueba que es un número, si tecleas una palabra no te dejará seguir y te seguirá pidiendo un número infinitamente.